# SQL Query Error - check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to figure out why the following SQL is failing:

```
INSERT INTO users ('c_id', 'c_email', 'c_fname', 'csname', 'c_mobile', 'c_add_1', 'c_add_2', 'c_city', 'c_county', 'c_postcode', 'c_comments') VALUES ('null','josh','hh', 'hh', 'hhhh', 'hh', 'hhh', 'hhh', 'hhhh', 'hh', 'hhh')
```

I have tried it without the c_id being null.

I am getting the following message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''c_id', 'c_email', 'c_fname', 'csname', 'c_mobile', 'c_add_1', 'c_add_2', 'c_cit' at line 1

Comment: try removing the ' from the field names, you only need backticks in special cases (reserved words, strange characters, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, single quotes (`'`) denote string literals, not object names. You should drop them from your column list:

```
INSERT INTO users (c_id, c_email, c_fname, csname, c_mobile, c_add_1, c_add_2, c_city, c_county, c_postcode, c_comments) 
VALUES ('null','josh','hh', 'hh', 'hhhh', 'hh', 'hhh', 'hhh', 'hhhh', 'hh', 'hhh')
```